# How to keep line numbers from Word while saving as .htm

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, numbering

I'm converting Word docx documents to .htm in order to post process the documents in an external tool.

What I am missing at the moment are line numbers we can see in Word while the Layout -> Line Numbers is enabled. Is there a way to keep those line numbers while converting to .htm using File -> Save As function? If not, is there an existing approach / script that can add correct line numbers as Word Layout -> Line Numbers function does?

Comment: Line numbers are totally a product of formatting and the print driver in Word. When you move to .htm that is normally set by window size and screen display. You might be better off saving as .pdf with the line numbers and then converting the .pdf to .htm.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesKenyon! I totally agree and understand your point, however I need to save the docx to htm. If I go through the PDF then I need another conversion pdf -> htm. If no existing solution, I am thinking to write a VBA script that will add line numbers in front of each line of the document.

Comment: That procedure will need to also change the margins and put a line break at the end of each line.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon, yes, sure, it is not so streight forward to do. Another more elegant solution, I would be glad to test it,